# .net MVC How do I download a file and stay on the same page?

Tags: c#, .net, http, model-view-controller

I am developing a page where a user can download a `.zip` containing a number of `.pdf files`. The functionality handling the download and the compressing works fine, my issue is that when I press the download button, it puts my page into an endless loop. It is as if it is loading the next `View`, but since the `ActionResult` returns a `File`, not a `View` or a redirect, it will never get to load a page. I have tried to set the `formtarget` to `_blank`, so that the download opens in a new tab, but that still puts the original tab in an endless loop.

Here is my `controller` method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DownloadCertificatesByModel([Bind(Include = "OrderNumber,ChosenLanguages,ChosenTemplates")] OrderViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var certificates = GetCertificatesByOrderNumber(viewModel.OrderNumber, viewModel.ChosenLanguages, viewModel.ChosenTemplates);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach(var cert in certificates)
                    {
                        //If the file actually exists
                        if (cert.Value)
                        {
                            zipArchive.CreateEntry(cert.Key.CertificateName);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", viewModel.OrderNumber + "_certificates.zip");
            }
        }
```

Here is the part of my `Razor View` in question:

```
<input type="submit" value="Download All Certificates" class="btn btn-default" formaction="DownloadCertificatesByModel" style="margin-right:10px" formtarget="_blank" />
```

**How can I have a `controller` action that returns a file but keeps the current page as it is, meaning no redirecting or anything, just initiating a download?**

**UPDATE:**
I should mention that the two "Chosen" variables from the model are `List<SelectListItem>` which means that when I try to follow `@cacalonga's` suggestion (change `POST` to `GET`), I get an error that the query string exceeds the max allowed length. To solve this I have tried to increase the `MaxQueryLength` in the `Web.config`, but this does not work either as the query is extremely long as it contains all the `SelectListItems`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use httpget method.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DownloadCertificatesByModel([Bind(Include = "OrderNumber,ChosenLanguages,ChosenTemplates")] OrderViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var certificates = GetCertificatesByOrderNumber(viewModel.OrderNumber, viewModel.ChosenLanguages, viewModel.ChosenTemplates);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach(var cert in certificates)
                {
                    //If the file actually exists
                    if (cert.Value)
                    {
                        zipArchive.CreateEntry(cert.Key.CertificateName);
                    }
                }
            }

            return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", viewModel.OrderNumber + "_certificates.zip");
        }
    }
```

On cshtml side:

```
<form action="/YourActionController/DownloadCertificatesByModel" method="get">
<input type="text" name="OrderNumber" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ChosenLanguages" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ChosenTemplates" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Download All Certificates" class="btn btn-default" />
```

/form>

Comment: That is very vague, could you elaborate?

Comment: you just change HttpPost to HttpGet and change html form element method="get"

Comment: have you try ? is it ok?

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement it and your suggestion makes sense. However, since I need information from the model, the current query string being sent for the GET request is way too long. This was not an issue when POST'ing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have tried to increase the allowed query string length, but 8156000 is still not enough, so I think I should find a different approach.

Comment: hi. you can use html form to get method instead query string, so you can still submit your model.Yesterday, I try on .net core 5.0 it's work. when the submit form, at the begining page start looping but stoped after downloaded the file.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but I will give it a try next week.

Comment: I do not understand how I can use the get method **instead** of query string, as I have tried to use the formmethod=get which automatically uses query string.

Comment: You right get method use querystring. I have try to show on answer. I hope this work for you.